# Magento trying to find js in skin/base folder instead of skin/custom-theme folder

Tags: layout, javascript, theme

I have added a custom js file to the head in the cart

```
  <checkout_cart_index>
    <remove name="top.links" />        
    <remove name="left.reports.product.viewed" />

    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>Primaapi/index.js</name><params/></action>
    </reference>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

There are two other custom js folders getting rendered from my skin/custom-theme folder so I'm sure the new theme is set up correctly. But for some reason when it comes to this specific file magento is trying to load it from the base theme.

From the browser it looks like this

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mysite.localhost/shop/skin/frontend/base/default/Primaapi/index.js">
```

Why is it checking the base folder and not my custom theme

Comment: It'll look in the base folder when it can't find the file in the theme's skin folder. Double check that your path's are correct inside `skin/frontend/`.

Comment: you were right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a path issue so when magento couldn't find it it searched the base directory for it. I had the file inside a js folder inside the skin folder which I had left out of the call.